# Quando sinalizo uma pergunta não conta como sinalização após privilégio de fechar

Tags: debate, medalhas, sinalização, privilégios

Depois que adquiri o privilégio de votar para fechar, sempre que sinalizo uma pergunta/resposta, não conta como sinalização, vai direto como voto para fechar.

É normal isso?

Pergunto porque nesse caso não contam mais as sinalizações, e consequentemente não é possível adquirir as medalhas que faltam por quantidade de sinalizações úteis.

Comment: Sim, se você já possui o privilégio de votar fechamento, não muito sentido poder sinalizar fechamento. Mas sinalizações não são somente disso, você pode sinalizar perguntas/respostas com baixa qualidade, comentários inadequados, dentre outros inúmeros motivos existentes no site.

Comment: Obrigado @Articuno, imaginei que fosse isso e faz sentido. Embora eu não seja um maludo por medalhas, é uma pena que só faltavam poucas sinalizações para adquirir mais uma medalha de prata :(

Comment: Mas você ainda pode sinalizar uai, perguntas e respostas de baixa qualidade, spam, respostas que não são respostas, tudo conta pra medalha ;)